# How to trim zeros after decimal value without changing the datatype using PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, decimal, trim

My requirement is to remove trailing zeros from decimal value, I have tried regex and `strip()` to remove trailing zeros it worked but we use regex and strip for string datatype, I want `Col_2` to be decimal without changing the precision and scale. Can someone please suggest alternative.

Sample Table :

> Col_1 : string
>
> Col_2 : decimal(18,2)

| Col_1 | Col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 2.00 |
| DEF | 2.50 |
| XMN | 0.00 |
| RST | 1.28 |

Actual Result using regex:

> Col_1 : string
>
> Col_2 : string

| Col_1 | Col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 2 |
| DEF | 2.5 |
| XMN |  |
| RST | 1.28 |

Expected Result :

| Col_1 | Col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 2 |
| DEF | 2.5 |
| XMN | 0 |
| RST | 1.28 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decimal(18,2)` type will always store those **2 digits** after the comma. Displaying the trailing zeros on the right side of the comma is just a matter of formatting.
So, if you want `Col_2` to be in decimal and preserve the precision then store it as `decimal(18,2)` and format it as you want when displaying the data.

You can use for that [`format_number`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#format_number) function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn("Col_2", F.expr("format_number(Col_2, '0.##')")).show()

#+-----+-----+
#|Col_1|Col_2|
#+-----+-----+
#|  ABC|    2|
#|  DEF|  2.5|
#|  XMN|    0|
#|  RST| 1.28|
#+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Hi, If i don't know which one is decimal but i need to trim leading zeros in my dataframe which has decimals only. How we can do this? Can you please suggest me